# is there any way to have text under each increment of the jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider, uislider

looking at this example of the jquery ui slider

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps

i want to be able to show the values of the increments under each "increment point".  so in this example it would show 0, 50, 100, etc . . .

is this possible or do i have to align text underneath and hope it lines up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Filament Group as done something like that with there plugin that makes a [jQuery UI Slider from a select element](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/)

Comment: Any idea how to implement this with multiple dynamically generated selects?

Comment: Yes! Ensure that all your `select` elements have an `id=''`